# Using a URL Parameter in Angular View?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, rxjs, axios

I recently started learning Angular/Node, and managed to call an API Endpoint and the pass the data to my view.

I did this by specifying my name manually in the URL, I now want to make it so I can change the name in the URL, and pull the corresponding data, through. I've managed to get it work in Express as below:

```
//Get Summoner Specific
router.get('/summoner/:summoner', (req, res) => {
    axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/' + req.params.summoner, {
        headers: head
    })
    .then(summoner => {
        res.status(200).json(summoner.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

So when I go to /get/summoner/TYPENAME I see the correct data passed back. I now want to display this data on a page using Angular.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SummonerService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Get all posts from the API
  getSummoner() {
    return this.http.get('/get/summoner/:summoner')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SummonerService } from '../summoner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summoner',
  templateUrl: './summoner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summoner.component.css']
})
export class SummonerComponent implements OnInit {

  summoner: any = [];

  constructor(private summonerService: SummonerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Get Summoner from API
    this.summonerService.getSummoner().subscribe(summoner => {
      this.summoner = summoner;
    });
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<p>
  summoner works!
</p>

{{ summoner.name }}
{{ summoner.id }}
```

However when I go to /summoner/TYPENAME (hoping to see the data displayed within the view)

```
(node:9916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Seems like the problem could most likely be in the template, and you've forgotten to include that.

Comment: Apologies, I've added it now, albeit its very simple.

Comment: What's up with that url tho? using `:` is pretty unusual. But I know nothing about express so can't really help you further, but I can say the rest of the code looks alright, except the template, if `summoner` is an array you should iterate it, `{{summoner.name}}` doesn't exist, but it shouldn't be the the reason for the error though.

Comment: I may be wrong as I'm also learning, but I think the :summoner defines the query param? Also, its not an array and it loads fine when I use it through /get/ (my API endpoint) as soon as I try to pass it to the view I get the error. Thanks again for looking :)

Comment: Can anyone help? :(